# Finite Field with no Order

Tags: logic

Question:
Let F be a field, that is, a set with operations $+$ and $\cdot$
    which satisfy the axioms of the definition of an "ordered field".
    Prove that if $F$ is finite (i.e. has only finitely many elements), then
    there does not exist an ordering $<$ which makes $F$ into an ordered
    field.

How can I go about proving a finite field has no order?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: There is a positive integer $n$ such that $\underbrace{1_F+1_F+\ldots+1_F}_{n\text{ copies}}=-1_F$.